# can't get rid of the spaces between the links

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I'm trying to make a simple responsive navigation but i can't seem to eliminate the spaces inbetween the links. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

This is my code:
css:

```css
.nav{
 width:100%; text-align:centre; margin:0 auto;max-width:1010px;
}
.nav ul{
 line-height:50px;
}
.nav li{
 display:inline; list-style-type: none;border-right:#333333 1px solid;
}
.nav li:hover{
 
}
.nav a{
 text-decoration:none; padding:10px; color:#000; font-family: sans-serif;
}
.nav a:hover{
 color:#c00;background:#999999;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="nav"><!-- nav -->
        <span class="menu-button"></span>
        <ul class="clearfix menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</div><!--/nav-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just switched your css a bit from  display: inline to float: left for the li tags. Hope it helps, though float may not be the best approach here.

```
.nav li {
display: inline;
}
```

to

```
.nav li {
float: left;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyVLOK

Answer (score 1):

With CodeRomeos answer, most of the spacing/padding was removed but there was still some spacing between the links. From your request to ***eliminate*** the spacing between the links then the below solution will completely remove spacing (although it would look better IMO with at least some padding between links).

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: centre;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 1010px;
}
.nav ul {
  line-height: 16px;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-right: #333333 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav a:hover {
  color: #c00;
  background: #999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <span class="menu-button"></span>
    <ul class="clearfix menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot. i was pulling my hair out trying to figure it out ahahaha

Answer (score 0):

As in your css `there is padding defined` 10px.

```
.nav a{
text-decoration:none; padding:10px 5px; color:#000; font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

set it to

```
.nav a{text-decoration:none; padding:10px 2px; color:#000; font-family: sans-serif;}
```

Hope this help you.!